# Databricks error:Internal error, sorry. Attach your notebook to a different cluster or restart the current cluster

Tags: databricks

I'm working in databricks 8.1. If I’m running my Pyspark code line by line using `Shift + Enter` then my code is running fine but if I’m running the entire notebook using `Run All` button then I’m getting internal error message. The complete error message is

```
Internal error, sorry. Attach your notebook to a different cluster or restart the current cluster.
com.databricks.rpc.RPCResponseTooLarge: rpc response (of 20984709 bytes) exceeds limit of 20971520 
bytes at com.databricks.rpc.Jetty9Client$$anon$1.onContent(Jetty9Client.scala:370) at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.client.api.Response$Listener$Adapter.onContent(Response.java:248) at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyContent(ResponseNotifier.java:135) at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyContent(ResponseNotifier.java:126) at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.responseContent(HttpReceiver.java:340) at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.content(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:283) 
at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseContent(HttpParser.java:1762) at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1490) at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.parse(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:172) 
at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:135) 
at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:73) 
at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:133) 
at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:151)    
at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) 
at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at   shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:426) 
at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:320) at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:158) at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336) at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313) 
at 
shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171) 
at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129) 
at  shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:367) at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:782) at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:914) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Several times, I restarted the cluster but still I'm getting same issue
Can you suggest me the steps to resolve this issue?

Comment: show the code  that cause this error